# Forward port to another machine on FreeBSD 6.2

Tags: freebsd, port, port-forwarding

I'm in the process of shutting down an old FreeBSD 6.1 server, but I need to port foward 80 & 443 to its replacement while I wait for those naughty ISPs that cache DNS records longer than my TTL to get their act together.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**L7 solution:**
You can use [nginx](http://sysoev.ru/en/) as a reverse proxy and redirect all requests from old IP to new with simple config like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default ssl;

    server_name www.YOURDOMAIN.com YOURDOMAIN.com;

    #SSL SETTING MUST BE HERE

    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://NEW_IP_HERE/;
        proxy_set_header  Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

**L4 solution:**
pf.conf:

```
rdr on rl0 proto tcp from any to YOUR_OLD_IP port 80 -> YOUR_NEW_IP 
rdr on rl0 proto tcp from any to YOUR_OLD_IP port 443 -> YOUR_NEW_IP
```

Do not forget to replace `rl0` with your network card name

Then do

```
# kldload pf
# pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
# pfctl -e
```

Answer (score 1):

With apache, you can do something like that.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect permanent / http://new.domainname.fr/
ServerName *.domainame.fr
    ServerName domainame.fr
</VirtualHost>
```

Using a subdomain will force the a new DNS request. Later you can force the redirection from new to www.

But maybe there is the same domain name and you are just waiting for the DNS to be updated. Then HTTP redirection will not work and some iptable forwarding can be usefull.

```
ipfw add divert 80 tcp from any to ${my_ip} 80 via ${local_if} in
ipfw add divert 443 tcp from any to ${my_ip} 443 via ${local_if} in
```

Or you can also put a blank page :

```
The site is moving, you have to update your DNS to IP_ADDRESS.
```

Good luck

Comment: Copying's not good =P

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Setup a proxy, or create simple HTTP "Location:" redirection. The more simple - the better: its temporary, don't waste time :)

Comment: To me, port forwarding is simpler. Location won't work as the only way users are getting to the old server, is if their DNS isn't up to date

Comment: ssh forwarding won't be useful: 80 & 443 ports are already occupied on that server. Then you'll need to make your server a router so it forwards everything there (divert with ipfw): it's something like `ipfw add divert 1234 tcp from any to ${my_ip} 123 via ${local_if} in`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NetCat, it can listen on a port, redirect to another port on another server

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/58 is an example of how to do it.